# HTML5 two buttons on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am new to use HTML5.

I have five HTML5 text boxes with required field set on and one image uploader with required field set on. Now on the click of button one or two all the six input types generates required alerts one by one.

What is want - on click of button "upload image" it should only check the requiredness of file uploader only.

on click of button "save data" it should check the remaining five input text boxes.

Basically i want a functionality which should be same as "ValidationGroup" in c#.net. Means there must have some selective validation of form attributes.

**[upload image should only validate "CHOOSE FILE"]**

**[Recharge now should validate all the controls except "CHOOSE FILE"]**

below is the live screen shot of my page...

[image]

Comment: Can you post your ASPX page code?

Comment: I guess the idea is to perform the validation on the client side using JavaScript. If yes, what JS framework do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform client-side validation with JavaScript, you might be using some application framework like AngularJS. As this is what I'm using I would say it does the job pretty well. Here is the official documentation with planty of examples and documentation - http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms.

Comment: Miroslav Nedyalkov,
Is there any thing like vaidation group in html5 or what ever because i an not able to understand the angularjs.